# Run PHP Results inside WP Shortcode

Tags: php, shortcode

How would I put the below results into the WP Short code?

**PHP Results:**

```
    <?php

 function endsWith($haystack, $needle) {
     // search forward starting from end minus needle length characters
     return $needle === "" || (($temp = strlen($haystack) - strlen($needle)) >= 0 && strpos($haystack, $needle, $temp) !== FALSE);
 }

 $lastDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('today - 30 days'));
 $todayDate = date('Y-m-d');

 $results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM `ucsite_statistics_pages` WHERE id=1428 AND `date` BETWEEN '$lastDate' AND '$todayDate' ", ARRAY_A );
    for($i=0;$i<count($results);$i++)
    if (endsWith(get_site_url().''.$results[$i]['uri'], 'http://universitycompare.com/universities/the-uni-of-westminster/')) {
        echo $results[$i]['count'];
        echo ',<br />';  } ?>
```

How do I insert the above 'if results' that are being echoed out into the below shortcode?

```
<?php 
echo do_shortcode('[wp_charts title="linechart" canvaswidth="976px" canvasheight="244px" relativewidth="4" width="976px" height="244px" type="line" align="alignright" datasets=" { data to be here } "]'); 
?>
```

Comment: edit your question to show us the code of your shortcode

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have a shortcode called `wp_charts` that accepts a pramaeter `datasets`, and you want to create a new shortcode that runs a database query and embeds the results of the query as the value of `datasets`?

If so, there are several ways to do this, but I think the easiest - especially if you didn't write `wp_charts` yourself - is to create a new shortcode that runs the query and then calls the `wp_charts` shortcode.

For example:

```
function my_charts_with_data_shortcode_impl($atts, $content = null) {
    $sql_query = ...
    $results = $wpdb->get_results($sql_query, ARRAY_A );
    $datasets = [];
    foreach ($results as $row) {
        if (endsWith(get_site_url().''.$row['uri'], 'http://universitycompare.com/universities/the-uni-of-westminster/')) {
            $datasets[] = $row['count'];
        }
    }

    return do_shortcode('[wp_charts '.
        'title="linechart" canvaswidth="976px" canvasheight="244px" relativewidth="4" '.
        'width="976px" height="244px" type="line" align="alignright" '.
        'datasets="'. join(",",$datasets) . '"]');
}
```